# PayPal transactions not going through with standard integration

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to implement purchasing with PayPal
https://github.com/paypal-examples/docs-examples/tree/main/standard-integration

I set up a PayPal business account and entered my client-id and secret into the env variable and into the Index.html (I assume its supposed the be the same client ID in both, correct?)

I followed the instructions, except I didn't log in with my sandbox ID, instead I just sent money with CC

```
Create an application
Rename .env.example to .env and update CLIENT_ID and APP_SECRET
Replace test in public/index.html with your app's client-id
Run npm install
Run npm start
Open http://localhost:8888
Click "PayPal" and log in with one of your Sandbox test accounts
```

I have a couple issues:

1. I followed the instructions `npm install` and `npm start`
   I tried sending the default amount to myself, but I dont see anything in the account, eventhough all of the transaction steps were completed in the paypal popup, I entered my CC info and etc. Am I missing something? Is the backend automatically started if I follow those instructions, or maybe it's not starting the backend?
2. I cant seem to change the payment value from the front end,
   I did a search and found `value: "100"` in paypal-api.js, and set it there to $1,
   I want to set the price using an external shopping cart, how can I set the value from Index.html?
3. What does the sandbox account actually do? I don't see any instructions on how to use it, I have a username and password for it, does it send money from myself to myself?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A sandbox account is like a live account, except in the sandbox environment, which is for development testing. There is never any reason to use a real credit card in the sandbox environment. Use a sandbox account, or a generated card.

If you sent money to a sandbox account, the transaction will be visible in the receiving sandbox account's account interface. Log into it at [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) .  See your sandbox apps and accounts in

- [www.developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/sandbox](http://www.developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/sandbox)
- [www.developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts](http://www.developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts)

Which of course you should have configured your application with in the first place when in sandbox mode.

> how can I set the value from Index.html?

Index.html should not set values, index.html should set selected products and quantities in the body of the request. Values should be calculated by the backend using this information.

You may prefer the sample at https://github.com/paypal-examples/paypal-sdk-server-side-integration , it is somewhat more fleshed out. Remove the onShippingChange callback from the button HTML if you want its Debit or Credit Card form to expand inline; that callback and calculation does not work with the inline form.